# Read .PART files

Tags: python-3.x, dask, large-data

I am building a model which used large datasets in .csv files (~50Gb). My machine is a Windows 10 with 16Gb of RAM.

Since I don't have enough RAM to load the whole dataset, I used [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) to read the file and split them into smaller data sets. It worked just fine and I was able to save it into files like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K9TR.png). However, when I read the files, it only showed `...` in every boxes like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W63Pc.png)

I have tried

```
!pip install dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

cat = dd.read_csv(paths.data + "cat.csv/*")
cat.head(5)
```

but it simply kept loading even though the data is kept to a minimum.
Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `...` symbol is expected, since the data is not loaded in memory. There is a detailed tutorial on dask dataframes here: https://tutorial.dask.org/04_dataframe.html

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem with mine was because even if I have separated the dataset into smaller sets, each one still have a large amount of columns. So when I tried `cat.head(5)`, it still took a long time to figure out which type each column is. To only use the 1st part of the the dataset, I used `cat = dd.read_csv(paths.data + "cat.csv/001.PART")` instead.